# Perl CGI::Session, Multiple Sessions with same IDs, MySQL Driver

Tags: database, perl, session, cgi

I have some problem with CGI::Session.

I try to create a new session with an existing session id passed with the cgi object. Normally the session should reuse the existing session in the database, but it doesn't. Instead it creates a new session database entry with the exact same session id.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
CGI::Session->name("DCGISESSID");


$session = CGI::Session->new('driver:mysql', $cgi,
    {
        TableName=>'DSESSIONS',
        IdColName=>'id',
        DataColName=>'a_session', 
        Handle=>$dbh,
    });


$sessioncookie = CGI::Cookie->new(-name=>'DCGISESSID', -value=>$session->id, -expires=>'+1h', -path=>'/');
```

The code works as long as I do not set the cookie name with the name() method and use the default value CGISESSID as cookiename. But for some reason, after changing it to DCGISESSID with CGI::Session->name("DCGISESSID"); it doesn't work.

Does someone got the same problem or has any advice for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. I configured the table false, that's why id wasn't a primary key too.